# Problem with k-points with pw2wannier

Tags: quantum-espresso, band-structure, hse06, wannier90, bandgap

I am calculating the band structure using HSE06 using wannier method. I have manage to perform the scf calculations and first processing of wannier.x to generate the .nnk file. but when I run the pw2wannier.x the following error occur. I don't know what caused this error as I generate the k-point using the kmesh.pl method. your help is hilgy appreciated.

````
G-vector sticks info
     --------------------
     sticks:   dense  smooth     PW     G-vecs:    dense   smooth      PW
     Sum       10805    5417   1481               713315   252257   35969

     Using Slab Decomposition

     Reading collected, re-writing distributed wavefunctions

  Spin CASE ( default = unpolarized )

  Wannier mode is: standalone     

  -----------------
  *** Reading nnkp 
  -----------------

  Checking info from wannier.nnkp file

  - Real lattice is ok
  - Reciprocal lattice is ok
  Something wrong! 
  k-point            3  is wrong
   0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000       0.79226244387103761     
   0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000      -0.39613122589683109     

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     Error in routine pw2wannier90 (3):
     problems with k-points
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```
````

Comment: Please fix the formatting.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I fixed your formatting. Please note that for a block of code or output file text, it is better to use ``` at the beginning and end to get code block.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you used open_grid.x in order to expand the k-point grid from IBZ to full BZ. In this case the k-point mesh should be taken from the output of open_grid.x.

Also I found that when using open_grid instead of non-SCF run (at least in QE v.6.5) it is needed to manually rename files in scratch directory, i.e. pwscf_open -> pwscf

Hope it could help

Update, useful links:

1. https://christoph-wolf.at/2018/10/10/band-structure-calculations-in-qe-using-hybrid-functionals/
2. [Calculating HSE06 band structures on Quantum ESPRESSO](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1176/calculating-hse06-band-structures-on-quantum-espresso)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes. thank you very much for your answer. it was really helpful.

Comment: @MubarakYagoub if it was "really helpful", why didn't you upvote it?

Comment: [By UPD do you mean "update"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72607/391772)? I couldn't find the meaning of UPD anywhere using Google when searching phrases like "UPD acronym" and "UPD internet slang", then when I looked at the revision history on this answer I noticed that UPD was added when you made your update, so I search "UPD update" and found the above-linked Meta post. **But why don't you just type "update" instead of UPD?** Does it save you or anyone else any time?

Comment: @NikeDattani, the reason is simple. First I wrote P.S., then changed it to UPD. Of course this is short for "update". I did not expect that this decrease the readability.